# Android Studio does not remember configured modules

Tags: android-studio

Everytime I restart Android Studio it forgets the configured modules despite them shown as configured in the `ProjectStructure>Dependencies` menu and I manually have to remove them from `ProjectStructure>Dependencies` and then add them again.

I also tried invalidating the chache, cleaning and rebuilding but the only thing that works is to manually remove the dependencies and to add them again.

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I never faced this problem, but i would check this points:

- Do you have other software like git accessing the project folder and maybe overriding some important project files?
- Does your user have the rights to write data into the project folder and the configuration files?
- Does the Event Log shows something interesting?
- Does the log shows something? `Help > Show Log in Files > idea.log`
  i recommend using Ctrl+F to find any occurrence of `Error`

If you are on linux you can use `find -cmin -30` to get a list of all files that were changed in the last 30 minutes. That might be useful to spot the problem.

It might help if you give us your operating system (and version) and android-studio version.

Comment: I managed to isolate the file "changes that cause the issue". Basically on ever START of android the *.iml files for each used used module gets changed. The following entry gets removed after android studio is done loading from SpaceGameModel.iml:
 "<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="SpaceGameModel.SpaceGameModel" level="project" />"

I'm using Addroid Studio 3.4.1 and the project is git version controlled. There is no write permission conflict I think. I uploaded a log file containing A start, adding the modules, restarting IDE log https://pastebin.com/rpNKQCP2